# Flutter: Reorderable list i just want to move part tile in list

Tags: flutter

Flutter: Reorderable list i just want to move part tile in list
suppose: List is coming
1 aaaaaaa
2 bbbbbbb

use can drag aaaaaa but 1 remain at its position
1 bbbbbb
2 aaaaa

only a will move not 1 when will drag tile from list

Comment: Try this  https://github.com/Tbsdev-Anmol/Task_Manager.git

Comment: @Ayush can you edit your question and provide some code so someone can diagnose the issue with your code and give a proper solution?